# How to calculate the integral from 0 to 1 of g(0):=0 and otherwise g(x)=sin(1/x)?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

My text book asks me to prove that this is Riemann integrable. I can't figure out how to prove that, but anyway I'm far more interested in how to find the value of the integral on [0,1]. How would you go about that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Substitute $x=1/t$ and integrate by parts. The final result involves a [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html).